# Golang Regex MatchString Escape Char Dash

Tags: regex, go

Does the sequence of dash (-) in regex matter. In case below cases, validID1 no escape char mentioned before dash (-) and test case failed. If I add escape char in validID1 ((`^[abcd1234\-_.]$`)) then test case passed.
Where as in validID2 with out providing escaper char test case passed. Why it is behaving differently.

```
var validID1 = regexp.MustCompile(`^[abcd1234-_.]$`) //  No escape is provided
var validID2 = regexp.MustCompile(`^[abcd1234+-\/]$`) // No escape is provided for(-) but provided for (/)

fmt.Println(validID1.MatchString("adc-")) // false
fmt.Println(validID2.MatchString("adc-")) // true
```

Comment: "Why it is behaving differently." ... "`// true`": [they both return false](https://go.dev/play/p/SZar7fzVpu3)

Comment: @erik258 here is Go playground both are returning false. What's the correct way to escape dash in regex ?

Comment: Can you provide an accurate description of your problem, since we agree your code does not do what you say it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dash `-` inside a class (denoted by square brackets `[..]`) is a special metacharacter
(inside of classes). They represent a *range* of characters where `= from char - to char`

If you want it to be a literal Dash, you'd have to escape it `\-` or put it at the beginning or
end of the class which removes the ambiguity.

So in your examples this is what those classes match

`[abcd1234-_.]`  matches `.123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_abcd`

`[abcd1234+-/]`  matches  `+,-./1234abcd`

*Outside of a class, a dash has no special metacharacter meaning.*

Comment: can you please elaborate more what you mean by " If you want it to be a literal Dash, you'd have to escape it \- or put it at the beginning or
end of the class which removes the ambiguity.."

Comment: I can add literal dash [abcd1234\-_.] beginning and  [abcd1234-\ _.] end like this ?

Comment: The literal dash is either beginning `[-...]` end `[...-]` or middle `[..\-..]`. Also the escaped dash can go anywhere in the class, beginning, middle, oe end. It's just a literal then.

Comment: why is this matches ^[abcd1234-_.]$ matches .123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_abcd. It should only match abcd1234-_

Comment: `4` codepoint is \x34. Dot `.`  codepoint is \x2E. Cant go backwards begin range < end range only. In this case `[abcd1234-.]` won't compile. I've got software that instantly gives all codepoints that match a regex geared towards the Unicode UCD, like classes

Comment: Thanks for clarification appreciate your inputs